# Help me identify this B'twin Rockrider

Tags: identify-this-bike

I bought this bike like an hour and a half ago for $60 and I cant find the exact model. I am not really a bike guy so I'd appreciate some help :)

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%27Twin

Comment: Aside from that it’s a BTwin bike, a private label for relatively generic mass manufactured bikes, there’s not much point determining its exact model. Just ride and enjoy it.

Comment: Another means of having a greater chance at identifying a bike is to show it from right is also the right as in correct side. It gives a better view at at the chainrings, both derailleurs which can at least say something of the range.

Comment: Next time, ask the seller for all the information.  Some people keep paperwork from the initial purchase, which can help with "lifetime" frame warranties etc.  You can always ask the seller later.

Answer (score 4):

bTwin is the bike brand from the big French multisports chain Decathlon. Their bicycle sales are quite big in France, Spain and Belgium. Rockrider is the name for the MTB line. Usually there are numbers attached to indicate its rank. From your picture it is probably their Rockrider 5.2. This is an entry level type. It dates from 2005-2010.

[image]

See a review of the Rockrider 5.2 in https://www.bikeradar.com/gear/category/bikes/mountain-bikes/product/review-decathlon-rockrider-5-2-8964/